# Upgrade sonar to 3.7.2

Tags: upgrade, sonarqube, profiles, is-empty

I made a bad sonar upgrade from 3.4.1 to 3.7.2. I did not upgrade plugins first, and directly upgrade sonar to 3.7.2. After that I found sonar cannot be started due to plugin consistency issue. I removed all plugins and restart sonar. Sonar started normally, but all quality profile rules are empty now, even after I re-installed all plugins from upgrade center. Any ideas?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known limitation. See http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-4642 and http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-4764. For now, the only way to get back the default profiles is to export them from a fresh install and import them into your production instance.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any possibility to recover custom rules back besides the default ones?

Comment: You can restore your database backup on a fresh install of SonarQube and then export/import.